# Javascript Library for Diagram Creation?

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, javascript

Which JavaScript library (free or commercial) can build computer network diagrams or electrical diagrams. Also, that supports animations between different items in the diagrams etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Noone has mentioned GoJS (http://www.gojs.net), which looks powerful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out these three libraries and see if they can help you out:

**[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)**

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library
>   that should simplify your work with
>   vector graphics on the web. If you
>   want to create your own specific chart
>   or image crop and rotate widget, for
>   example, you can achieve it simply and
>   easily with this library. Raphaël
>   ['ræfeɪəl] uses the SVG W3C
>   Recommendation and VML as a base for
>   creating graphics. This means every
>   graphical object you create is also a
>   DOM object, so you can attach
>   JavaScript event handlers or modify
>   them later. Raphaël’s goal is to
>   provide an adapter that will make
>   drawing vector art compatible
>   cross-browser and easy.

**[Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)**

> Protovis composes custom views of data
>   with simple marks such as bars and
>   dots. Unlike low-level graphics
>   libraries that quickly become tedious
>   for visualization, Protovis defines
>   marks through dynamic properties that
>   encode data, allowing inheritance,
>   scales and layouts to simplify
>   construction. Protovis is free and
>   open-source, provided under the BSD
>   License. It uses JavaScript and SVG
>   for web-native visualizations; no
>   plugin required (though you will need
>   a modern web browser)! Although
>   programming experience is helpful,
>   Protovis is mostly declarative and
>   designed to be learned by example.

**[Processingjs](http://processingjs.org/)**

> Processing.js is the sister project
>   of the popular Processing visual
>   programming language, designed for the
>   web. Processing.js makes your data
>   visualizations, digital art,
>   interactive animations, educational
>   graphs, video games, etc. work using
>   web standards and without any
>   plug-ins. You write code using the
>   Processing language, include it in
>   your web page, and Processing.js does
>   the rest. It's not magic, but almost.
>
> Originally developed by Ben Fry and
>   Casey Reas, Processing started as an
>   open source programming language based
>   on Java to help the electronic arts
>   and visual design communities learn
>   the basics of computer programming in
>   a visual context. Processing.js takes
>   this to the next level, allowing
>   Processing code to be run by any HTML5
>   compatible browser, including current
>   versions of Firefox, Safari, Chrome,
>   Opera, and Internet Explorer.
>   Processing.js brings the best of
>   visual programming to the web, both
>   for Processing and web developers.

Comment: These are great for diagrams that are not user-driven.  For user-driven diagram creation, I recommend goJS (http://www.gojs.net).

Answer (score 15):

The answer is absolutely [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com)

Comment: It's a pity that JointJS' user-driven diagram creation library, Rappid, does not allow trial usage.

Answer (score 11):

Try the free online app for drawing diagrams, [draw.io](https://www.draw.io). It uses [mxGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) library for drawing diagrams.

Disclaimer :

I'm a software developer associated with JGraph.

Answer (score 5):

....last but not least [Draw2D](http://draw2d.org/draw2d_touch/jsdoc/#!/example).

it's a JS lib for easy diagram creation. The API is more like a Java/C# syntax. Abstraction and management layer above the famous RaphaelJS lib.

Code Example:

```
      var canvas = new draw2d.Canvas("gfx_holder");

      // Create two standard nodes for "start" and "end" and link
      // this figures with a standard Connector
      //
      var start  = new draw2d.shape.node.Start();
      var end    = new draw2d.shape.node.End();

      canvas.addFigure(start, 80,180);
      canvas.addFigure(end, 450,250);

      // Add a connection via API calls between Start and Stop
      //
      var connection = new draw2d.Connection();
      connection.setSource(start.getOutputPort(0));
      connection.setTarget(end.getInputPort(0));
      canvas.addFigure(connection);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Google charts:
   http://code.google.com/intl/uk/apis/chart/
2. Dojo: http://dojotoolkit.org/grids-charts
3. ExtJS: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-3

Comment: none of them can create netowrk diagrams or electrical diagrams. they are good for charting. Thanks for the reply.